# How to organize maven dependencies into single Maven Dependencies library folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've imported a maven project into my workspace in eclipse luna. It's been imported as a maven project, however I see all my dependencies all over the place (see screen capture below), in fact it appears they're all redundant, same dependencies exist inside the Maven Dependencies library folder. For some reason I can't just delete them. How can I delete these redundant dependencies or organize this project to have just to have the dependencies in the 'Maven Dependencies' library folder?

[image: Notice there is also a Maven Dependencies folder which contains the same dependencies as shown outside the folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using eclipse, install eclipse maven plugin from market place ,after that when you will do right click on the project it will show you a option `Maven` ,click on this inside this you have plenty of other option click on `Disable Maven Nature`  so `Maven`  will disable from project.

[image]

then `Right click on your project -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Select all M2_REPO lib` and Remove them and then press `Ok` Button.

[image]

Now Again right click on the same project `Configure-> Convert to Maven project`

[image]

when it is done `Right click on project Maven->Update Project`.

[image]

It will add maven dependency inside a `Maven Dependencies` . Something like this

[image]

Also it will resolve lots of Maven issue of the project.

Answer (score 0):

- Select on All the jars and do Right click + Build path Remove from build path.(Make sure you know what jars you need or copy all of them in folder if you want)
- Then Right click on Project Name
  Go to Build Path and Click Configure Build Path.
- Go to Libraries Tab and Click Add Library
  Then select User library
- On the right side there is a button -User Libraries Click that
- Then click on New Button on right side. Create a new library by giving a meaningful name.
- You will see your user library on the left side.
- Select that library. You will see Add External Jars option on the right side.
  Now Select all the Jars that you need and add it in here(You can select these jars from m2 folder or from your custom folder you created in step 1 above).
- You will be back to "Add Library Menu" Now you will see your library with all its jars present inside it.
- Check the checkbox and click Finish.

And now your project look organized !!

Comment: it might look organized, but you know have to manage your dependencies twice: once in maven and once in eclipse.

Comment: Doing this deleted my dependency from within the Maven Dependencies library folder too